# Problem with functions in C (readability)

Tags: c, function, cs50

I am working on an exercise in cs50 pset2 readability, and I'm trying to count up how many sentences there are in a text. So far my code is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int isdelim(char c, int sentences)

int main (void)
{
   string text = get_string("Text: ");
   int sentences = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text);i++)
   {
 sentences = isdelim(text[i], sentences);
   }

   printf("Sentences: %i\n", sentences);
}

int isdelim(char c, int sentences)
{
    return c == '.' || c == '!' || c == '?';
    sentences++;
}
```

But when I do `./readability` and I type the text: `Hello, world! Beautiful day!`, it gives an output of: `Sentences:0`.

I am new to C so I can't really understand all these functions. I tried searching the web and using other external sources, but nothing makes sense. If you show me the answer, please make sure to tell me why it works, so I can learn. I may need the knowledge in the future. Thanks a lot.

Comment: **Protip:** You're not calling the function `isdelim` with `int isdelim(char c, int sentences);` syntax.

Comment: Also, you have a return statement before incrementing sentences, so if i'm not wrong, it's never gonna be executed...

Comment: @Lost in code: Try compiling with all warnings on: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror`

Comment: I did compile with all warnings. clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    readability.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o readability

Comment: Whoever put the downvote to my question/post, can you tell me why you placed it so I can fix the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Baramar makes some good points but I think the code could use a refactoring. The `isdelim` function is confusing. It's named as a Boolean function, so it should return a `bool`. And that function shouldn't take a `sentences` parameter; rather, let the caller handle the incrementing. And I've taken the liberty to call `strlen` before the loop so it doesn't get recomputed on each iteration. So:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<ctype.h>

bool isdelim(char c);

int main (void)
{
   string text = get_string("Text: ");
   int sentences = 0;
   int length = strlen(text);

   for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
   {
      if (isdelim(text[i]))
      {
         sentences++;
      }
   }

   printf("Sentences: %i\n", sentences);
}

bool isdelim(char c)
{
    return c == '.' || c == '!' || c == '?';
}
```

Comment: On your answer it types the following error message:

Comment: clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    readability.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o readability
readability.c:45:20: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 1
if (isdelim(text[i]))
    ~~~~~~~        ^
 
1 error generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'readability' failed
make: *** [readability] Error 1

Comment: I’m guessing you still have an instance of `isdelim` with the `sentences` parameter. Probably in the forward declaration.

Comment: Ok i'll try that.

Comment: Thanks alot it worked. It printed the correct number of sentences. By the way, do you happen to know(or think you know) why someone put a downvote on my post? I want to fix the problem. Thanks a million.

Comment: Don’t know, sorry.

Comment: It's ok. If you have a guess why they placed it, like if you spot a problem in my post, please tell me. Ty.

Answer (score 4):

There's several problems.

1. When you execute a `return` statement, the function ends. Nothing after that will be executed. So `sentences++` is never executed.
2. In C, function parameters are passed by value. So incrementing `sentences` in the `isdelim()` function will not affect the variable in `main()`.
3. `int delim(char c, int sentences);` is a function declaration, not a function call. Function calls don't include the type declarations.

You can solve the first problem by using an `if` statement that checks the condition, rather than returning the result of the condition immediately.

You can solve the second problem by passing a pointer to the variable and dereferencing it, or by having the function return the new value of `sentences`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int isdelim(char c, int sentences);

int main (void)
{
   string text = get_string("Text: ");
   int sentences = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text);i++)
   {
       sentences = isdelim(text[i], sentences);
   }

   printf("Sentences: %i\n", sentences);
}

int isdelim(char c, int sentences)
{
    if (c == '.' || c == '!' || c == '?') {
        sentences++;
    }
    return sentences;
}
```

Comment: On the ` sentences = isdelim(text[i]);` part, it prints this error message: readability.c:45:30: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 1
  sentences = isdelim(text[i]);
              ~~~~~~~        ^
readability.c:7:2: note: 'isdelim' declared here
 int isdelim(char c, int sentences);
 ^
1 error generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'readability' failed
make: *** [readability] Error 1

Comment: Indeed, isdelim expects two arguments and the above code only passes one.

Comment: I added the argument